# Installable Trigger randomly fires multiple times upon form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-workspace

I have a Google Form which submits the filled out data to a Google Sheet. With the help of an installable trigger (firing up whenever a form is submitted) I managed to copy the most recent row into a new sheet by appending a new row with this data. However sometimes the trigger randomly fires multiple times and therefore appends 2 or more rows with the exact same values into the other sheet. I am convinced the trigger is the problem, since I found an evidence of the trigger firing multiple times in the G Suite Developer hub overview page of the triggers.
Anyone else experiencing the same problems or know what workarounds would work?

**EDIT**:
Here's the complete code. I have 2 sheets, one called "FormResponse" where the form inputs gets copied automatically. And a second sheet called "Checkliste", where an installable trigger fires whenever a form response comes in. It then triggers the function "insertIntoChecklist()". I have a second installable trigger for "edited()". The method is not implemented yet. However it will be needed in the future to trigger a method when a user edits the "Checkliste" sheet.

The installable triggeres are set within the G Suite developer hub:

[image: Triggers]

```
function edited() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  switch(sheet.getSheetName()){
    case "Checkliste":
      //checkIfFinished(); --> Method will be implemented later
      break;
    default:
      Logger.log("Unknown Sheet name in onEdit method!");
  }
}

// Method to insert into the Checklist sheet depending on the team
function insertIntoChecklist() {
  // Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // FormResponse
  var formResponse = ss.getSheetByName("FormResponse");
  var lastRowFormResponse = formResponse.getLastRow();

  // Values FormResponse
  var prename = formResponse.getRange(lastRowFormResponse, 2.0).getValue();
  var surname = formResponse.getRange(lastRowFormResponse, 3.0).getValue();
  var team = formResponse.getRange(lastRowFormResponse, 4.0).getValue();
  var date = formResponse.getRange(lastRowFormResponse, 5.0).getValue();

  // Checklist
  var checklist = ss.getSheetByName("Checkliste");
  var lastRowChecklist = checklist.getLastRow();
  lastRowChecklist++;
  // Values Checklist
  var googleAccount = checklist.getRange("E" + lastRowChecklist);
  var phone = checklist.getRange("F" + lastRowChecklist);
  var workstation = checklist.getRange("H" + lastRowChecklist);

  // Based on the submitted team create instantiate a method that gets evoked
  switch(team){
    case "Immo":
      createImmo(checklist, prename, surname, team, date, email, googleAccount, phone, workstation);
      break;
    case "IT":
      createIT(checklist, prename, surname, team, date, email, googleAccount, phone, workstation);
      break;
    default:
      checklist.appendRow(["no team detected"]);
  }
}


var hardwareTypes = {
  winPC : "- Windows PC\n",
  iMac:  "- iMac\n",
};

var phoneTypes = {
  hardphone : "- Hardphone\n",
  softphone : "- Softphone\n"
};

function createImmo(checklist, prename, surname, team, date, email, googleAccount, phone, workstation) {
  checklist.appendRow([prename, surname, team, date]);
  addCheckbox(googleAccount);
  addCheckbox(phone);
  addNote(phone, phoneTypes.softphone);
  addCheckbox(workstation);
  addNote(workstation, hardwareTypes.winLap);
}

function createIT(checklist, prename, surname, team, date, email, googleAccount, phone, workstation) {
  checklist.appendRow([prename, surname, team, date]);
  addCheckbox(googleAccount);
  addCheckbox(phone);
  addNote(phone, phoneTypes.hardphone);
  addCheckbox(workstation);
  setNotAvailableCell(checklist);
}

function addCheckbox(checkboxRange) {
  var enforceCheckbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
  enforceCheckbox.requireCheckbox();
  enforceCheckbox.setAllowInvalid(false);
  enforceCheckbox.build();
  checkboxRange.setDataValidation(enforceCheckbox);
}

function addNote(range, note) {
  range.setNote(note);
}

function setNotAvailableCell(checklist) {
  var rowRange = checklist.getRange(checklist.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 
checklist.getLastColumn());
  var values = rowRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= 0; i++){
    for (var j = 4; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      var currentValue = rowRange.getCell(i+1,j+1);
      var currentRange = 
checklist.getRange(currentValue.getRow(),currentValue.getColumn());

      if (values[i][j] !== false && values[i][j] !== true) {
        currentRange.setValue("n/a");
        currentRange.setBackground("#A9A9A9");
        currentRange.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)